# How to read an existing xml file from sdcard and add new data into it

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I just want to read xml file from the sdcard and want to add some new data into it. Then I have to write it into sdcard. How can I implement it. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Iam able to read and write data but iam unable to append data to existed xml file.Could you help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading and Writing XML files sample is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631894/720176). And you can get plenty of them using [google](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=reading%20and%20writing%20xml%20files%20in%20android&aq=0&oq=reading%20and%20writing%20xml%20files%20in%20a&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=reading%20and%20write%20xml%20file%20in%20android%20example&oq=reading%20and%20writing%20xml%20files%20in%20android%20e&gs_l=serp.3.0.33i29i30l2.67786.68155.0.69548.2.2.0.0.0.0.253.409.0j1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.38YUgYFpTIg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.bmk&fp=1f6c09e049400626&biw=1366&bih=656). However two important classes for this are `XmlSerializer` and `XmlPullParser`. A simple XmlSerializer example is:-

```java
public static String CreateXMLString() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException, IOException
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);

    //Start Document
    xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true); 
    xmlSerializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
    //Open Tag <file>
    xmlSerializer.startTag("", "file");

    XmlSerializer tempXml = Xml.newSerializer();
    StringWriter tempWriter =  new StringWriter();


    xmlSerializer.startTag("", "something");
    xmlSerializer.attribute("", "ID", "000001");

    xmlSerializer.startTag("", "name");
    xmlSerializer.text("CO");
    xmlSerializer.endTag("", "name");

    xmlSerializer.endTag("", "something");



    //end tag <file>
    xmlSerializer.endTag("", "file");
    xmlSerializer.endDocument();

    return writer.toString();
}
```

Similarly You can find one for XmlPullParser as well. Since you want to read / write files in sdCard don't forget to call `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` to obtain the Path of external Storage directory. See a simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5453753/720176).

Don't forget to add following line to your manifest file without that nothing will work.

If You don't get that working. Update your question with the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just to get the File using

```java
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "your_path/your_xml.xml");
```

after you can do xml parsing to read that file.