# When to save list data and re-load data in android app

Tags: android, json, list, csv, xamarin

I have created an app with two `activities` as the activities with two separate lists. 
Let's call them: `Activity1` and `Activity2`.
With the home screen of the app called the `MainActivity`.
As soon as the app is launched, the `MainActivity` is created and `notifications` appear in the notification bar based on the list item's statuses.

I've had a look at the lifecycle of Android but I can't understand and figure out where to load the lists and when to save the lists. Also, what is the best way to save large list data in Android to internal storage? `Json? Csv?` File type basically? :)

For example, would I load both lists when the MainActivity is first created, `onCreate()`. And then save the list of(for example) Activity1 when the user navigates away from Activity1, `onPause()`?

To reiterate, this is what I need help on: 
I've had a look at the lifecycle of Android but I can't understand and figure out where to load the lists and when to save the lists. Also, what is the best way to save large list data in `Android to internal storage? Json? Csv?` File type basically? :)

Thank you for any help! :)

Comment: You might also consider saving the data in a SQLite database, you can also create a backup routine to then save a copy to internal storage.  That gives you pretty good flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have already known, **onCreate** will be call when **Activity** is instantiated, so all initialization, including populating the Activity with list data loaded from a file or shared preference. In terms of when to save the list data, it totally depends on how you want to modify the data, as data only needs to be saved when it's changed from its original state.

Of course, you can also load data every time **onResume** is called, and save data again when **onPause** is called, just to make sure data is synchronized if you have multiple applications modifying the same list data.

There are many different ways to save list data. I would recommend to use **SharedPrefernce** as it will save you some troubles. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences) for how to save **ArrayList** to **SharedPreference**. If you don't like this, you can always save the data to a file with some standard format (JSON, XML, etc.) and parse the data when reading from and writing to the file.

Comment: Thank you, but do you also have a link to somewhere to show how the save data file such as XML to internal storage? List data to a file in internal storage? :) Can't seem to find one.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646757/write-and-read-a-json-data-to-internal-storage-android) is for JSON. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630844/read-write-to-external-xml-file-in-android) is for XML.

Answer (score 0):

A good entry point to load a data is in "OnResume". It is called every time your activity will be presented to the user.

Saving your data can be placed in "OnPause".

"OnCreate" is only called when the activity will be created, which will happen only once for your MainActivity.