# Unable to create XML file in android

Tags: android, xml, file-access

I am creating an `xml` file in which i want to save my data from my `app`. But i am getting the below exception in `logcat`

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-02 12:08:40.352 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
03-02 12:08:40.352 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at com.example.accurat.application.MainActivity$4.onPermissionGranted(MainActivity.java:192)
03-02 12:08:40.352 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at com.gun0912.tedpermission.TedInstance.onPermissionResult(TedInstance.java:65)
03-02 12:08:40.352 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-02 12:08:40.352 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at com.squareup.otto.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:89)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at com.squareup.otto.Bus.dispatch(Bus.java:385)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at com.squareup.otto.Bus.dispatchQueuedEvents(Bus.java:368)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at com.squareup.otto.Bus.post(Bus.java:337)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at com.gun0912.tedpermission.busevent.TedBusProvider.post(TedBusProvider.java:49)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at com.gun0912.tedpermission.TedPermissionActivity.permissionGranted(TedPermissionActivity.java:123)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at com.gun0912.tedpermission.TedPermissionActivity.checkPermissions(TedPermissionActivity.java:190)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at com.gun0912.tedpermission.TedPermissionActivity.onCreate(TedPermissionActivity.java:65)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2506)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
03-02 12:08:40.353 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
03-02 12:08:40.354 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:932)
03-02 12:08:40.354 16419-16419/com.example.accurat.application W/System.err:
```

In my manifest file i have the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Below is my code part in which i am getting error

```
   final PermissionListener ListenerSaveData = new PermissionListener() {
              @Override
              public void onPermissionGranted() {
                  if(refr_no == "Select a reference number" || meter_type == "Select Meter Type" || Latitude == " " || Longitude == ""
                          || site_status == "Select Site Status" || comm_status == "" || pole_type == "Select pole type" || DateTime == "" )
                  {
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Data not saved.... you must be missing some thing.. Please check!!! " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

                  }else {
                      int selectedRadioButton = rg_meter_placement.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                      rb_meter_placement = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedRadioButton);
                      Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                      SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                      DateTime = df.format(c.getTime());
                      comm_status = String.valueOf(comment.getText());


                          try {
                              File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + filename);
                              file.createNewFile();
                              FileOutputStream fileos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                              XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
                              StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                              xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);
                              xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null,"record");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null,"ref_no");
                              xmlSerializer.text(refr_no);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null,"refr_no");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null,"meter_type");
                              xmlSerializer.text(meter_type);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null,"meter_type");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null,"lat");
                              xmlSerializer.text(Latitude);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null,"lat");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null,"long");
                              xmlSerializer.text(Longitude);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null,"long");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null,"site_status");
                              xmlSerializer.text(site_status);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null,"site_status");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null,"communication_status");
                              xmlSerializer.text(comm_status);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null,"communication_status");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "pole_type");
                              xmlSerializer.text(pole_type);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null,"pole_type");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null,"meter_placement");
                              xmlSerializer.text(String.valueOf(rb_meter_placement));
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null,"meter_placement");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null,"date_time");
                              xmlSerializer.text(DateTime);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null,"date_time");
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null,"record");
                              xmlSerializer.endDocument();
                              xmlSerializer.flush();
                              String dataWrite = writer.toString();
                              fileos.write(dataWrite.getBytes());
                              fileos.close();
                          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                          catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                          catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                          catch (IOException e) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                      }



              }

              @Override
              public void onPermissionDenied(ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {

              }
          };
```

**Note**

I know there are a lot questions asked related to it but i couldn't find any better solution.

**Update 1**

For permission i am using `ted` as below

```
  btn_save_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(refr_no == "Select a reference number" || meter_type == "Select Meter Type" || Latitude == " " || Longitude == ""
                    || site_status == "Select Site Status" || comm_status == "" || pole_type == "Select pole type" || DateTime == "" )
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Data not saved.... you must be missing some thing.. Please check!!! " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

            }else {

                new TedPermission(MainActivity.this)
                        .setPermissionListener(ListenerSaveData)
                        .setRationaleMessage("This activity will need your permission to save file ")
                        .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        .check();
              }

        }
    });
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @cricket_007 i already have permission request

Comment: @cricket_007 kindly see my updated code

Comment: why did you add getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: @EliasFazel see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28421812/6854117)

Comment: I knew but you don't need it i think try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage3

Comment: Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is /storage/emulated/0filename  which could not be possible to create, use '/' between file name and storage location

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/" + filename);
                          file.createNewFile();
```

Comment: Where should i find the file in my mobile via connecting it to my system ?

Comment: This code snipset is from your onPermissionGranted method just update it there it will work properly.
File will be in your parent storage as you didn't mentioned any directory for it

Comment: Yes it's working and i can see my file but when i open it, it says unable to open the file and i can't find the file when i connect it through my system

Comment: Have you mentioned any file extension?

Comment: disconnect and connect your device again with your system and check

Answer (score 1):

Your need to add runtime permission for File create

Move your file related code to a separate method and call it when permission is granted.

For Example:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);  //add this code in onCreate()
```

Now:

```
if(isPermissionGranted()){
     do_your_work();  //create a method or write the whole code here
    }


 public  boolean isPermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}


 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 0: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //do your work call method
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
 }
```

Comment: it seems he implemented runtime permission

Comment: see the first line of the error:  `java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` and think op's implementation is right or wrong

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 thanks for the help man, but my permission handler is good enough. the problem is solved by following the `Anuj J Pandey` solution

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 it's correct and your code will also work i know :)